# Spring Annotation-Based Interceptor

Tags: spring, interceptor

can any of you please post a snippet for the following.  I've looked in a couple of places but they all seem to be xml based.  I'd like to have this code in java configuration style only.

I am trying to accomplish the following..

1) I need to intercept a specific url, for example "http://localhost:8080/test" and only a url that starts with "/test/*".  This is not a spring security question, this is just for an endpoint I like to intercept.

2) I need to intercept the HttpServletRequest object of that request and add a specific header to that request.  For example, "authorization", "bearer xxxx".

3) When the /test endpoint finally hits, I should be able to see the authorization header inside my HttpServletRequest object.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this:
(Whithin "YourOwnInterceptor" you can add the value to the header...)

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public YourOwnInterceptor yourOwnInterceptor() {
      return new YourOwnInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
        registry.addInterceptor(yourOwnInterceptor()).
           addPathPatterns("/<your-url-to-intercept>/**");
    }
```

}